# Workout the ffmpeg settings used to create a mp4

Tags: ffmpeg, whatsapp

I am almost 99% sure this is a particularly useless question. As you can see the codec information and they are identical. The information on the left does not work,when sharing with whatsapp, the version on the right does. They are from the same parent file and as far as I know, made with the same script. But the script has had some options added, the output from the script is:

```
ffmpeg  -i some.mp4 -s 1980x1080 -c:a copy sd.mp4
```

The end game here is to create files that are no larger than 64mb and then be able to share with friends.

This is a none helpful image showing how it looks with the "broken.mp4" file in whatsapp:
[image]

[image]

### Broken

```
General
Count                                    : 331
Count of stream of this kind             : 1
Kind of stream                           : General
Kind of stream                           : General
Stream identifier                        : 0
Count of video streams                   : 1
Count of audio streams                   : 1
OtherCount                               : 1
Video_Format_List                        : AVC
Video_Format_WithHint_List               : AVC
Codecs Video                             : AVC
Video_Language_List                      : English
Audio_Format_List                        : AAC LC
Audio_Format_WithHint_List               : AAC LC
Audio codecs                             : AAC LC
Audio_Language_List                      : English
Other_Format_List                        : QuickTime TC
Other_Format_WithHint_List               : QuickTime TC
Other_Codec_List                         : QuickTime TC
Other_Language_List                      : English
Complete name                            : broken.mp4
File name extension                      : broken.mp4
File name                                : broken
File extension                           : mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format/Extensions usually used           : braw mov mp4 m4v m4a m4b m4p m4r 3ga 3gpa 3gpp 3gp 3gpp2 3g2 k3g jpm jpx mqv ismv isma ismt f4a f4b f4v
Commercial name                          : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Internet media type                      : video/mp4
Codec ID                                 : isom
Codec ID                                 : isom (isom/iso2/avc1/mp41)
Codec ID/Url                             : http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/standalone.html
CodecID_Compatible                       : isom/iso2/avc1/mp41
File size                                : 24580128
File size                                : 23.4 MiB
File size                                : 23 MiB
File size                                : 23 MiB
File size                                : 23.4 MiB
File size                                : 23.44 MiB
Duration                                 : 20571
Duration                                 : 20 s 571 ms
Duration                                 : 20 s 571 ms
Duration                                 : 20 s 571 ms
Duration                                 : 00:00:20.571
Duration                                 : 00:00:20:33
Duration                                 : 00:00:20.571 (00:00:20:33)
Overall bit rate                         : 9559138
Overall bit rate                         : 9 559 kb/s
Frame rate                               : 59.940
Frame rate                               : 59.940 FPS
Frame count                              : 1233
Stream size                              : 34626
Stream size                              : 33.8 KiB (0%)
Stream size                              : 34 KiB
Stream size                              : 34 KiB
Stream size                              : 33.8 KiB
Stream size                              : 33.81 KiB
Stream size                              : 33.8 KiB (0%)
Proportion of this stream                : 0.00141
HeaderSize                               : 40
DataSize                                 : 24545514
FooterSize                               : 34574
IsStreamable                             : No
File last modification date              : UTC 2022-04-25 21:12:20
File last modification date (local)      : 2022-04-25 22:12:20
Writing application                      : Lavf58.29.100
Writing application                      : Lavf58.29.100

Video
Count                                    : 378
Count of stream of this kind             : 1
Kind of stream                           : Video
Kind of stream                           : Video
Stream identifier                        : 0
StreamOrder                              : 0
ID                                       : 1
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format/Url                               : http://developers.videolan.org/x264.html
Commercial name                          : AVC
Format profile                           : High@L4.2
Format settings                          : CABAC / 4 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, Reference frames        : 4
Format settings, Reference frames        : 4 frames
Internet media type                      : video/H264
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 20571
Duration                                 : 20 s 571 ms
Duration                                 : 20 s 571 ms
Duration                                 : 20 s 571 ms
Duration                                 : 00:00:20.571
Duration                                 : 00:00:20:33
Duration                                 : 00:00:20.571 (00:00:20:33)
Bit rate                                 : 9356655
Bit rate                                 : 9 357 kb/s
Width                                    : 1980
Width                                    : 1 980 pixels
Height                                   : 1080
Height                                   : 1 080 pixels
Stored_Width                             : 1984
Stored_Height                            : 1088
Sampled_Width                            : 1980
Sampled_Height                           : 1080
Pixel aspect ratio                       : 0.970
Display aspect ratio                     : 1.778
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Rotation                                 : 0.000
Frame rate mode                          : CFR
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
FrameRate_Mode_Original                  : VFR
Frame rate                               : 59.940
Frame rate                               : 59.940 (60000/1001) FPS
FrameRate_Num                            : 60000
FrameRate_Den                            : 1001
Frame count                              : 1233
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.073
Delay                                    : 48786850
Delay                                    : 13 h 33 min
Delay                                    : 13 h 33 min 6 s 850 ms
Delay                                    : 13 h 33 min
Delay                                    : 13:33:06.850
Delay_Settings                           : DropFrame=No / 24HourMax=No / IsVisual=No
Delay_DropFrame                          : No
Delay, origin                            : Container
Delay, origin                            : Container
Stream size                              : 24058967
Stream size                              : 22.9 MiB (98%)
Stream size                              : 23 MiB
Stream size                              : 23 MiB
Stream size                              : 22.9 MiB
Stream size                              : 22.94 MiB
Stream size                              : 22.9 MiB (98%)
Proportion of this stream                : 0.97880
Title                                    : GoPro H.265
Writing library                          : x264 - core 155 r2917 0a84d98
Writing library                          : x264 core 155 r2917 0a84d98
Encoded_Library_Name                     : x264
Encoded_Library_Version                  : core 155 r2917 0a84d98
Encoding settings                        : cabac=1 / ref=3 / deblock=1:0:0 / analyse=0x3:0x113 / me=hex / subme=7 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=1 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=1 / 8x8dct=1 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=-2 / threads=34 / lookahead_threads=5 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=3 / b_pyramid=2 / b_adapt=1 / b_bias=0 / direct=1 / weightb=1 / open_gop=0 / weightp=2 / keyint=250 / keyint_min=25 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=40 / rc=crf / mbtree=1 / crf=23.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:1.00
Language                                 : en
Language                                 : English
Language                                 : English
Language                                 : en
Language                                 : eng
Language                                 : en
Color range                              : Full
colour_range_Source                      : Stream
Codec configuration box                  : avcC

Audio
Count                                    : 280
Count of stream of this kind             : 1
Kind of stream                           : Audio
Kind of stream                           : Audio
Stream identifier                        : 0
StreamOrder                              : 1
ID                                       : 2
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AAC
Format                                   : AAC LC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec Low Complexity
Commercial name                          : AAC
Format_AdditionalFeatures                : LC
Codec ID                                 : mp4a-40-2
Duration                                 : 20566
Duration                                 : 20 s 566 ms
Duration                                 : 20 s 566 ms
Duration                                 : 20 s 566 ms
Duration                                 : 00:00:20.566
Duration                                 : 00:00:20:24
Duration                                 : 00:00:20.566 (00:00:20:24)
Bit rate mode                            : CBR
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 192000
Bit rate                                 : 192 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 2
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel positions                        : Front: L R
Channel positions                        : 2/0/0
Channel layout                           : L R
Samples per frame                        : 1024
Sampling rate                            : 48000
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Samples count                            : 987168
Frame rate                               : 46.875
Frame rate                               : 46.875 FPS (1024 SPF)
Frame count                              : 964
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Delay                                    : 48786850
Delay                                    : 13 h 33 min
Delay                                    : 13 h 33 min 6 s 850 ms
Delay                                    : 13 h 33 min
Delay                                    : 13:33:06.850
Delay_DropFrame                          : No
Delay, origin                            : Container
Delay, origin                            : Container
Delay relative to video                  : 0
Delay relative to video                  : 00:00:00.000
Stream size                              : 486535
Stream size                              : 475 KiB (2%)
Stream size                              : 475 KiB
Stream size                              : 475 KiB
Stream size                              : 475 KiB
Stream size                              : 475.1 KiB
Stream size                              : 475 KiB (2%)
Proportion of this stream                : 0.01979
Title                                    : GoPro AAC  
Language                                 : en
Language                                 : English
Language                                 : English
Language                                 : en
Language                                 : eng
Language                                 : en
Default                                  : Yes
Default                                  : Yes
Alternate group                          : 1
Alternate group                          : 1
```

### Working

```
General
Count                                    : 331
Count of stream of this kind             : 1
Kind of stream                           : General
Kind of stream                           : General
Stream identifier                        : 0
Count of video streams                   : 1
Count of audio streams                   : 1
OtherCount                               : 1
Video_Format_List                        : AVC
Video_Format_WithHint_List               : AVC
Codecs Video                             : AVC
Video_Language_List                      : English
Audio_Format_List                        : AAC LC
Audio_Format_WithHint_List               : AAC LC
Audio codecs                             : AAC LC
Audio_Language_List                      : English
Other_Format_List                        : QuickTime TC
Other_Format_WithHint_List               : QuickTime TC
Other_Codec_List                         : QuickTime TC
Other_Language_List                      : English
Complete name                            : working.mp4
File name extension                      : working.mp4
File name                                : working
File extension                           : mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format/Extensions usually used           : braw mov mp4 m4v m4a m4b m4p m4r 3ga 3gpa 3gpp 3gp 3gpp2 3g2 k3g jpm jpx mqv ismv isma ismt f4a f4b f4v
Commercial name                          : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Internet media type                      : video/mp4
Codec ID                                 : isom
Codec ID                                 : isom (isom/iso2/avc1/mp41)
Codec ID/Url                             : http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/standalone.html
CodecID_Compatible                       : isom/iso2/avc1/mp41
File size                                : 29826297
File size                                : 28.4 MiB
File size                                : 28 MiB
File size                                : 28 MiB
File size                                : 28.4 MiB
File size                                : 28.44 MiB
Duration                                 : 20571
Duration                                 : 20 s 571 ms
Duration                                 : 20 s 571 ms
Duration                                 : 20 s 571 ms
Duration                                 : 00:00:20.571
Duration                                 : 00:00:20:33
Duration                                 : 00:00:20.571 (00:00:20:33)
Overall bit rate                         : 11599357
Overall bit rate                         : 11.6 Mb/s
Frame rate                               : 59.940
Frame rate                               : 59.940 FPS
Frame count                              : 1233
Stream size                              : 34626
Stream size                              : 33.8 KiB (0%)
Stream size                              : 34 KiB
Stream size                              : 34 KiB
Stream size                              : 33.8 KiB
Stream size                              : 33.81 KiB
Stream size                              : 33.8 KiB (0%)
Proportion of this stream                : 0.00116
HeaderSize                               : 40
DataSize                                 : 29791683
FooterSize                               : 34574
IsStreamable                             : No
File last modification date              : UTC 2021-10-24 18:15:02
File last modification date (local)      : 2021-10-24 19:15:02
Writing application                      : Lavf58.29.100
Writing application                      : Lavf58.29.100

Video
Count                                    : 378
Count of stream of this kind             : 1
Kind of stream                           : Video
Kind of stream                           : Video
Stream identifier                        : 0
StreamOrder                              : 0
ID                                       : 1
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format/Url                               : http://developers.videolan.org/x264.html
Commercial name                          : AVC
Format profile                           : High@L4.2
Format settings                          : CABAC / 4 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, Reference frames        : 4
Format settings, Reference frames        : 4 frames
Internet media type                      : video/H264
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 20571
Duration                                 : 20 s 571 ms
Duration                                 : 20 s 571 ms
Duration                                 : 20 s 571 ms
Duration                                 : 00:00:20.571
Duration                                 : 00:00:20:33
Duration                                 : 00:00:20.571 (00:00:20:33)
Bit rate                                 : 11396917
Bit rate                                 : 11.4 Mb/s
Width                                    : 1980
Width                                    : 1 980 pixels
Height                                   : 1080
Height                                   : 1 080 pixels
Stored_Width                             : 1984
Stored_Height                            : 1088
Sampled_Width                            : 1980
Sampled_Height                           : 1080
Pixel aspect ratio                       : 0.970
Display aspect ratio                     : 1.778
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Rotation                                 : 0.000
Frame rate mode                          : CFR
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
FrameRate_Mode_Original                  : VFR
Frame rate                               : 59.940
Frame rate                               : 59.940 (60000/1001) FPS
FrameRate_Num                            : 60000
FrameRate_Den                            : 1001
Frame count                              : 1233
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.089
Delay                                    : 48786850
Delay                                    : 13 h 33 min
Delay                                    : 13 h 33 min 6 s 850 ms
Delay                                    : 13 h 33 min
Delay                                    : 13:33:06.850
Delay_Settings                           : DropFrame=No / 24HourMax=No / IsVisual=No
Delay_DropFrame                          : No
Delay, origin                            : Container
Delay, origin                            : Container
Stream size                              : 29305136
Stream size                              : 27.9 MiB (98%)
Stream size                              : 28 MiB
Stream size                              : 28 MiB
Stream size                              : 27.9 MiB
Stream size                              : 27.95 MiB
Stream size                              : 27.9 MiB (98%)
Proportion of this stream                : 0.98253
Title                                    : GoPro H.265
Writing library                          : x264 - core 155 r2917 0a84d98
Writing library                          : x264 core 155 r2917 0a84d98
Encoded_Library_Name                     : x264
Encoded_Library_Version                  : core 155 r2917 0a84d98
Encoding settings                        : cabac=1 / ref=3 / deblock=1:0:0 / analyse=0x3:0x113 / me=hex / subme=7 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=1 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=1 / 8x8dct=1 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=-2 / threads=18 / lookahead_threads=3 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=3 / b_pyramid=2 / b_adapt=1 / b_bias=0 / direct=1 / weightb=1 / open_gop=0 / weightp=2 / keyint=250 / keyint_min=25 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=40 / rc=crf / mbtree=1 / crf=23.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:1.00
Language                                 : en
Language                                 : English
Language                                 : English
Language                                 : en
Language                                 : eng
Language                                 : en
Color range                              : Full
colour_range_Source                      : Stream
Codec configuration box                  : avcC

Audio
Count                                    : 280
Count of stream of this kind             : 1
Kind of stream                           : Audio
Kind of stream                           : Audio
Stream identifier                        : 0
StreamOrder                              : 1
ID                                       : 2
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AAC
Format                                   : AAC LC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec Low Complexity
Commercial name                          : AAC
Format_AdditionalFeatures                : LC
Codec ID                                 : mp4a-40-2
Duration                                 : 20566
Duration                                 : 20 s 566 ms
Duration                                 : 20 s 566 ms
Duration                                 : 20 s 566 ms
Duration                                 : 00:00:20.566
Duration                                 : 00:00:20:24
Duration                                 : 00:00:20.566 (00:00:20:24)
Bit rate mode                            : CBR
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 192000
Bit rate                                 : 192 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 2
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel positions                        : Front: L R
Channel positions                        : 2/0/0
Channel layout                           : L R
Samples per frame                        : 1024
Sampling rate                            : 48000
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Samples count                            : 987168
Frame rate                               : 46.875
Frame rate                               : 46.875 FPS (1024 SPF)
Frame count                              : 964
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Delay                                    : 48786850
Delay                                    : 13 h 33 min
Delay                                    : 13 h 33 min 6 s 850 ms
Delay                                    : 13 h 33 min
Delay                                    : 13:33:06.850
Delay_DropFrame                          : No
Delay, origin                            : Container
Delay, origin                            : Container
Delay relative to video                  : 0
Delay relative to video                  : 00:00:00.000
Stream size                              : 486535
Stream size                              : 475 KiB (2%)
Stream size                              : 475 KiB
Stream size                              : 475 KiB
Stream size                              : 475 KiB
Stream size                              : 475.1 KiB
Stream size                              : 475 KiB (2%)
Proportion of this stream                : 0.01631
Title                                    : GoPro AAC  
Language                                 : en
Language                                 : English
Language                                 : English
Language                                 : en
Language                                 : eng
Language                                 : en
Default                                  : Yes
Default                                  : Yes
Alternate group                          : 1
Alternate group                          : 1
```

Comment: look under "Encoding Settings", where the "broken" one has `lookahead_threads=5` and the other has `lookahead_threads=3` maybe?

Comment: Interesting, I will check to see if you can change this in ffmpeg

Comment: Would you believe it... whatsapp just released an update that fixed this!!!